# Leverage Browser Caching js?ver=

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching, mod-expires

I'm facing an odd problem with my Leverage Browser Caching. In my `.htaccess` I use the following:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

This *successfully* caches my website. But the issue I'm facing is it is missing out some **non**-external JS files:

```
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/tracks/js/build/production.min.js?ver=4.7.2 (2 days)
http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1 (2 days)
http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4 (2 days)
http://exmaple.com/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7.2 (2 days)
http://example.com/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.7.2 (2 days)
```

I tried to fix it by adding the following lines, but the result was still the same:

```
ExpiresByType text/javascript “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType application/javascript “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType application/json “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript “access plus 1 month”
```

Any idea why it is not picking up the `js?ver=` and how to fix this problem? In case it helps:

**Hosting:** Hostinger

**Server:** Apache 2.4

Comment: You could check the content type they're being served as? And check there is not a .htaccess file in the WordPress directories overriding your root one. The 2 days makes it sound like they are being served as a content-type you don't have covered though. Are you sure the additions made no difference? And not a browser caching thing? Are you looking at the headers directly?

Comment: Thanks for your assistance @SuperDuperApps I looked back at the new four lines I wrote and have now gotten them to work. The issue was with the speech marks oddly enough.

Comment: Ah ha! Well spotted. Yes they're not in italics, although they do look that way, but "curly quotes", completely different quote characters. Usually found in word processing apps etc that use fancy looking quotes. [More info here](http://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html). You should accept your answer :)

Comment: Ohhh, that does make more sense :P..... I shall accept it tomorrow, not aloud to before then lol. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I managed to fix the issue. I was correct in using the following four lines:

```
ExpiresByType text/javascript “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType application/javascript “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType application/json “access plus 1 month”
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript “access plus 1 month”
```

However, the quotation marks around the `access plus` section are for some reason curly quotations. This was therefore returning `500` and `503` server errors. After replacing the quotation marks it has since fixed my issue and now correctly caches `js?ver=` files too.

My final Leverage Browser Caching code looks like this:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/json "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```